# How to update variable in From workspace block during runtime

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a sample model(shown below) which consist of a from workspace block. It contains a workspace variable variable1(timeseries signal). I am changing the data of variable1 during simulation but model is not updating the current value of variable1. It's update only when I stop and restart the simulation but I want it to update during runtime only. Can anyone help me in handling this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really how Simulink is designed to work, so there's no easy way to do this. Simulink only checks only checks the workspace for values during model initialization at the start of the simulation. The best thing to do is to use [`set_param`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/set_param.html), as in:

```
set_param('untitled/From Workspace',' VariableName','variable1'); % put the correct path to your block
```

This is not changing anything in how the block is parameterised, but forces Simulink to parameterise the block with the new values of `variable1`. Because `variable1` is a `timeseries` object, I am not sure how well this will work, but it's worth a try.

For more details, see [this discussion on MATLAB Central](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/242401).

Comment: I tried it but got error as follow:
FromWorkspace block does not have a parameter named 'Value'

So I tried with below command:
set_param(gcb,'Value','variable1');
it's not throwing error but it's not updating the variable runtime

Comment: Sorry, it looks like it's `'Data'`, not '`Value`'. Will update the answer.

Comment: `'VariableName'` even... See http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/block-specific-parameters.html#sources_lib_blkparams

Comment: I am getting following error

set_param('test12/From Workspace','Data','variable1');
FromWorkspace block does not have a parameter named 'Data'

set_param('test12/From Workspace','Value','variable1');
FromWorkspace block does not have a parameter named 'Value'

set_param('test12/From Workspace','VariableName','variable1');
this one is not throwing error but not updating runtime.

Comment: I think it is not updating because parameter VariableName  is not tunable, when model is running this parameter is non editable in dialog box, for e.g: if you try to change value of constant block then it will change (using set_param command) because it's parameter are editable during runtime;
    So is there any way to make it tunable?

Comment: `VariableName` is the correct parameter to change, I initially answered a bit too quickly without checking what the correct parameter name was. It might be worth trying saving the update data under a new variable, e.g. `variable2` and using `set_param` with that variable. If that doesn't work, then I'm out of ideas. As I said, this is not really how Simulink is meant to work.

Comment: it is also not working
set_param('test12/From Workspace','VariableName','variable2');
Cannot change parameter 'Data: (VariableName)' of 'test12/From
Workspace' while simulation is running

any way thanks for ur responses