# How do i give input from my GUI to my matlab simulation workspace struct()

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am currently working on a simulator implementing the lithium battery model on mathworks and i need to be ably to change a couple of the parametres when running the simulation from my GUI.

The original params reside within a workspace struct after compilation so i guess this is where i need to change the params.

the original file beeing read from is as follows:

```
%% Populate Lookup Tables
BatteryParams = struct();
for idx = 1:numCells

    %% Lookup Table Breakpoints
    BatteryParams(idx).SOC_LUT = [0 0.1 0.25 0.5 0.75 0.9 1]';
    BatteryParams(idx).Temperature_LUT = [5 20 40] + 273.15;

    %% Em Branch Properties (OCV, Capacity)

    % Battery capacity
    BatteryParams(idx).Capacity_LUT = [
        80.0000   79.5000   79.0000]; %Ampere*hours
```

now i want to be able to change the capacity of the battery during simulation but i have no real idea of how to do this since i am still relatively new to simulink.

I think it should contain :

```
command = sprintf('BatteryParams(%d).Qe_init = %f;', idx, value)
evalin('base', command);
```

But i am very unsure of how to implement this, in adition i need to be able to input for example 80Ah in my GUI and then get an array into the struct containing {80.5 80 79.5}

can anyone help me realize this ?

Answer (score 0):

Simulink is not really designed to do this, it only checks the (base) workspace for values during model initialization at the start of the simulation, see [How to update variable in From workspace block during runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29743613/how-to-update-variable-in-from-workspace-block-during-runtime/) for a similar question.

You can try using [`set_param`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/set_param.html) after changing the value of the parameter in the workspace, something like:

```
set_param(path_to_block,block_parameter_name,BatteryParams)
```

Replace `path_to_block` by the correct path to the block in question and `block_parameter_name` by the correct parameter you want to change for the block in question. If you are running this from the GUI, you may need to use `eval` or `evalin`.

Note also that this doesn't work for all blocks/parameters, as you can see in the other question previously mentioned.

Comment: Actually if I can change the parametre during a stop or pause of the simulation it is good enough. the point is that we dont want the user of the simulator to be bothered by having to change the values and compiling each time one wants to change the values.      I am also looking at the posibility to convert the library block so i can get the param as an input port instead but i have newer tried to create a library so that is a problem in itself.

Comment: You can also use `set_param` to pause/stop the model, e.g. `set_param(model_name,'SimulationCommand','pause')` after which you can try changing the parameter value with `set_param` before starting the simulation again. As you say, having the parameter as an input would be a better solution, but that will some work/effort to develop and debug.

Comment: How do i use the set_param in the simulink program from the GUI ?

Comment: Try it from the MATLAB command line first to check it actually works, then move to the GUI, probably using `evalin`.

Comment: I actually figured out how to modify my current lib so if i can figure out how to take an int and make i into an array of three numbers the Ah is set correctly.   a = {[a+0.5 a a-0.5]} or something like it